# Make header stick at certain window width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So my question is how would i make my header which already sticks to top on scroll only work on certain device width?

```
function fixDiv() {
  var $div = $("#header-full-top");
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) {
    $('#header-full-top').css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'top': '0',
      'width': '100%'
    });
  } else {
    $('#header-full-top').css({
      'position': 'static',
      'top': 'auto',
      'width': '100%'
    });
  }
}

$("#header-full-top").data("top", $("#header-full-top").offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5xxjbn2/1/)

Comment: use media queries in your CSS, and to fix your header you can use position:fixed.

Comment: I meant in javascript

Comment: then to track window width.. you can use $(window).width(); by using jQuery library..

Comment: if you look at my code the header changes at mobile width on full size. its different.. how would i make it so it looks like the mobile view when scroll?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 and how do i add window width to my current code?

Answer (score 0):

```
        function fixDiv() {
            var getWindowWidth  = $(window).width();
            //approximate above medium screen widths includes large and medium screens.
//exactly not sure, from where the medium screen sizes starts from, just you need to change 767 in order to checkout your result
            if(getWindowWidth>767) {
                $('#header-full-top').css({
                  'position': 'fixed',
                  'top': '0',
                  'width': '100%'
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#header-full-top').css({
                  'position': 'static',
                  'top': 'auto',
                  'width': '100%'
                });
            }
        }
        fixDiv();
        $(window).resize(fixDiv);
```

check the above code, `$(window).width()` returns the window width on which your web page or document is being called. accordingly you can utilize the width value to conditionally apply css using jquery or other statements according to window width.

https://jsfiddle.net/L5xxjbn2/2/

Comment: I dont know if i clearly stated my question but I wanted it to be on top of the navbar then on scroll it will move with the scroll

Comment: You have mentioned header-full-top as an targeting element, so accordingly I created the fiddle. If you want some other element to be targeted then simply change header-full-top to something which required.